# Is it possible to edit each product (name color, price color, font, etc) css in category page depending on a certain attribute?

Tags: product, category, css, edit

I have 1 category, and 2 attributes which i can sort by, for example boys and girls and i would like the products that have 1 attribute to have certain colors, for example blue for boys and pink for girls for certain things like product name and others.

Comment: do you want to change in the product view page right?

Comment: @jay  did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to have an overall class you can watch. For example an extra body class. We can add that with the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`.

Your `config.xml` would have the following observer

```
<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        [...]
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <[namespace]_[module]_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore</method>
                    </[namespace]_[module]_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
        [...]
    </frontend>
    [...]
</config>
```

And you `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php` class would look like

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore($o)
    {
        $this->_addBodyClass($o);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addBodyClass($o)
    {
        $_block = $o->getBlock();
        $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        if ($_block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html && $_product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
            $block->addBodyClass('sex-'.$_product->getData('sex'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your attribute in the product page.You can check the attribute from that and according to your attribute you can call the css classes.

```
$atr = $product->getAtribute();
//You can retrieve the css class according to your product attribute in phtml file
<h1 <?php if($atr=="boys"){?>class="product-title-boys" <?php }
          elseifif($atr=="girls"){?> class="product-title-Girls"<?php} ?>>
          <?php echo $product->getName(); ?>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

as in year 2022 you don't need to add customised module to achieve this as there are two useful body classes added automatically and smartly/dynamically (using browsing sequences) by Magento core, on both catalog entities, i.e. category page and product page.

One example is like following,

```html
<body class="catalog-product-view product-plan-toys-tableware categorypath-products-eco-toys category-eco-toys page-layout-1column preloaded">
    ...
</body>
```

This is done by Magento core as in version 2.4 (not sure earlier versions as lack of experience) through `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php`